# General solution for 1st order differential equation $(1-\sqrt{3})\frac{dy}{dx} + y\sec x = y^{\sqrt3}\sec x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find general solution for

$$(1-\sqrt{3})\frac{dy}{dx} + y\sec x = y^{\sqrt3}\sec x$$

What I tried

$$y^{-\sqrt3}(1-\sqrt{3})\frac{dy}{dx} + y^{1-\sqrt3}\sec x = \sec x$$

Then,
$u=y^{1-\sqrt3}  \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dy}=(1-\sqrt3)y^{-\sqrt3}$
$\frac{du}{dx}+u\sec x=\sec x$

$$e^{\int \sec x \,dx}=e^{\ln |\sec x+\tan x|}=\sec x+\tan x$$

$$(\sec x+\tan x)\frac{du}{dx}+u(\sec^2x+\tan x\sec x)=sec^2x+\tan x\sec x$$

$$\frac{d{\bigl((\sec x+\tan x)u\bigr)}}{dx}=\sec^2x+\tan x\sec x$$

After integrating both sides - $\int dx$,
$$(\sec x+\tan x)u=\sec x+\tan x\\
u=1=y^{1-\sqrt3}\\
y=1$$

Where am I doing the mistake ?

Comment: Put ```\``` before special functions to get it formatted properly. E.g. ```\sec(x)``` to get $\sec(x)$ and not $sec(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the constant

$$ (\sec x + \tan x) u = \sec x + \tan x \color{red}{+ C} $$
$$ u = 1 + \frac{C}{\sec x + \tan x} $$

$$ y = u^{1/(1-\sqrt 3)} = u^{-(1+\sqrt3)/2} = \left[ 1 + \frac{C}{\sec x + \tan x} \right]^{-(1+\sqrt3)/2} $$

Comment: +1 Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it's a Bernoulli differential equation.  Substitute $y = u^{1/(1-\sqrt{3})}$ to get a linear differential equation in $u$.

Comment: Can you show me how

Answer (score 0):

You may separate the variables:

$$(1-\sqrt{3})\frac{dy}{dx} = (y^{\sqrt3}
-y)\sec x.$$

Write this as $$\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{y^{\sqrt3}
-y}\mathrm d y= \sec x\mathrm d x.$$ Then integrate both sides.

Comment: Can you show me the solution ?

Comment: @HarshitGupta I've added more explanation above.

Comment: Left side of this equation is very hard to integrate.If you have a easier method please demonstrate it